# Can a child view controller be the delegate of its parent view controller?

Tags: swift, delegation

Lets say there are two classes, class A and class B. Class B is a child view controller of A.

```
protocol ClassADelegate: class{
     functions
}
class A {
     code
     add B as child view controller
}


protocol ClassBDelegate: class{
     functions
}
class B {
     code
}
```

Considering that class A is the parent view controller of B, My question is if class A is a delegate of class B and class B is a delegate of class A, does that create an ownership cycle? Is this bad practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent should be the child's delegate.

The parent, if it needs to tell the child something, should just invoke methods.

Comment: That actually makes perfect sense because there would only be one strong reference from the parent to the child therefore not creating an ownership cycle. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, assuming the strong reference is the child view controller reference.

Answer (score 1):

Delegates in Cocoa are stored as weak references. Weak references can't keep objects alive the way strong references do, thus you have no risk of strong reference cycles.

However, I can't think of a situation in which this would make sense. It's not really a delegate pattern anymore, it's just 2 objects arbitrarily messaging each other.

Comment: I have map view controller and a table view controller as its child view controller. I need to do event based synchronization between the parent and the child view controllers.

Comment: Then that's not delegation anymore.

Comment: Please enlighten me with more elaboration as to what it is called?

Comment: Delegation is the idea of "I don't care how you do it, just do this", such as when a marketing director might tell their underlings to "raise sales by 20%". He/she doesn't care how it's done, they just want to see results. Conceptually, delegation only works in one way. If the underlings delegated the task back up to the marketing director and said "raise sales by 20%", you'll just end up going in circles.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you're doing, but it's not delegation

Comment: Thank you for your response. Well I need two objects to communicate with each other and I saw the "don't care" feature of delegation and the weak references a better solution than say creating strong references of my object in either the parent or child view controllers and inevitably creating an ownership cycle. I might be wrong. Do you have any other solutions to solving this problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126949/discussion-between-alexander-momchliov-and-a-jam).

Answer (score 0):

> if class A is a delegate of class B and class B is a delegate of class A, does that create an ownership cycle? Is this bad practice?

It doesn't necessarily produce a reference cycle. Normally, an object doesn't retain its delegate. As to whether it's bad practice, that depends. It's unusual, in that you'd normally expect that a delegate would have a lifetime at least as long as the object that it's delegating for, while you'd expect a child view controller to have a shorter lifetime than its parent. Without knowing more about your intended design, it's impossible to say for sure.